# Entity Framework scaffold and related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

I'm building a simple app to learn Entity Framework, roughly following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) and [this](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/10/21/how-to-create-relationships-between-entities-in-the-entity-framework-code-first-approach.aspx) tutorials.

I've successfully code-first created my tables, I can query them and see the expected data and the correct keys for my one-to-many relationship with my seeded data.

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public Guid OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

}

public class OrganizationMemberContext : DbContext
{
    public OrganizationMemberContext(DbContextOptions<OrganizationMemberContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

I continued on to create a scaffolded controller for the `Organization` model using the OrganizationMemberContext, and that works beautifully. CRUD operations appear to be operating as expected.

I then wanted to display each organization's list of members under that organization on the index page. However... what I think should work returns no related data.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.Members);
    return View(await _context.Organizations.ToListAsync());
}
```

I get the list of Organizations, but each Organization's Members property is empty in the Model sent to the page (confirmed watching locals in VS).

**Again, the seeded data is being inserted correctly**: I can see in the DB where Organization.ID values precisely match Member.OrganizationID values as expected.

Comment: This may work for you : 
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Organizations.Include(x =>.Members).ToListAsync());
}

Comment: try the include inside the query its self.  _context.Orgranizations.Include(x=>x.Members).ToListASync());

Comment: The include is called in the first statement, not in the second one where you render the view

Comment: Somebody post that as an **answer** please, it works...

Comment: seems like Lazy Loading is still working - might disable it by using `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` inside context constructor. If that helps then Include should be used in await part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.Members); // use include with no additional queries 
    return View(await _context.Organizations.ToListAsync()); // made a new query - it knows nothing about include part - Lazy loading still in effect
}
```

Should be:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.Members)ToListAsync()); // query see include and add this information in the result
}
```